# Show that if $3\mid(a^2+1)$ then $3$ does not divide $(a+1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $3\mid(a^2+1)$ then $3$ does not divide $(a+1)$.

using proof of contradiction

can someone prove this using contradiction method please

Comment: $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$ and $A\implies B$ is only false if $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Comment: It is correct that there is no integer $a$ such that $a^{2}+1$ is divisible by $3.$ I leave the logical consequences of this for you to think about.

Comment: $\ a+1 = 3k\ $ so $\ a = 3k-1,\,$ not $\ 3k+1\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

For the original question, if $3 \nmid a$, then $3 \nmid a^2$ since $3$ is prime (consider the factorization of $a$ and $a^2$), but this doesn't imply anything about whether $3$ divides $a^2 + 1$.

Here's a different approach: Suppose $3$ is a divisor of both $a^2 + 1$ and $a + 1$. Can you justify why $$3 \mid \Big( a(a + 1) - (a^2 + 1)\Big) = a$$

and why that's a contradiction?

Comment: since $3\nmid a^2$ and since $3\nmid 1$ then it does not divide the sum of them

Comment: @user142405 No: $3 \nmid 2$ and $3 \nmid 1$, but $3 \mid 2 + 1$.

Comment: but there is a theorem which states that if $a\mid b$ and if $a\mid c$ then $a\mid b+c $

Comment: @user142405 Yes, but that does not imply the statement with everything negated. So it's true that $$a | b \text{ and } a | c \implies a | (b + c)$$ but it is *not* true that $$a \nmid b \text{ and } a \nmid c \implies a \nmid (b + c)$$

Answer (score 2):

$3\mid \color{blue}{a^2\!+\!1},\,\color{#0a0}{a\!+\!1}\,\Rightarrow\,3\mid\color{blue}{a^2\!+\!1}-\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}{a\!+\!1})(a\!-\!1)}^{\large a^2\,-\,1} = \color{#c00}2,\,$ a contradiction, completing your proof.

**Or** modly: $\ 3\mid a\!+\!1\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ a\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\ a^2\!+\!1\equiv \color{#c00}2\,\Rightarrow\,3\nmid a^2\!+\!1$

**Remark** $\ $ The first proof shows more generally that $\,\gcd(a^2+1,a+1)\mid 2.\,$ Using parity  we see further that the gcd $= 2 \iff a$ is odd; otherwise the gcd $= 1\ \ (\!\iff a\,$ is even$)$.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive:

> If $3\mid a+1$, then $3\nmid a^2+1$.

Which is easy, because then $a=3k-1$ and $a^2+1=9k^2-6k+2$, which isn't divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** just consider the 3 cases
$$a = 3k, a=3k+1, a=3k-1
$$